# JavaScript & JQuery not working correctly in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, maxmind

As a novice at JS I am pretty happy to get a script with the MaxMind API working in webkit browsers, however, IE didn't want to come to the party (and I thought it was only CSS/HTML issues that plagued IE!)

The page that I am testing can be found here - http://www.ontrackdatarecovery.es/images/phone/130612-es-dynamic-phone-geoip.html

As you should be able to see, it works in Chrome etc, but not in IE (8). Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: what does your console say in IE8?

Comment: What do you mean by "works" or "not works"?

Comment: And why don't you post relevant code here?

Comment: It would be helpful if you pointed out what part of the code is causing you an issue. I.e. put the code into your question.

Comment: IE8 doesn't like switch statement very much. Try with if/else.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear about what 'worked' and 'didn't work', and considering it was a full HTML page I thought it might be easier to just share the link and then people could view the page in different browsers easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Console says `'return' statement outside of function`.
Try changing that `return` statement to `break`

```
default:
    regionPhone = '<p>This is an IP from ' + userCountry + '</p>';
    break;
```

Comment: Try `+` operator to concatenate strings, rather than the bitwise `&`

Answer (score 0):

In IE, the variable `regionPhone` is undefined. Apparently, this is due to your `return` statement (IE says: `return statement outside of function`), as Mark mentions.

How about wrapping your logic into `$(function() {})` which will make sure the logic is run when the DOM is loaded. Also, it avoids having global variables.

Something like:

```
$(function() {
    var userRegion = geoip_region();
    var userCountry = geoip_country_code();
    var regionPhone;

    switch (userCountry) { 
    case "GB":
    var region = {};  
        // and so on

    $(".Regional-Phone").html(regionPhone);
    document.write('<p>Country: ' + userCountry + '<br>Region: ' + userRegion + '<br>City: ' + geoip_city() + '</p>');

});
```